# -PHP- Log request and response headers

Tags: php, logging

I need to log to a file an array in this format :

```
`Array
(
    [Date] => Thu, 15 Jun 2017 13:06:37 GMT
    [Server] => Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2f PHP/5.6.18
    [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.6.18
    [Content-Length] => 7790
    [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
)`
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What are you logging? How are you logging? What do you have now? What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is file_put_contents :

```
int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )
```

Seems easy to use. However, it seems like passing an array doesn't keep the key, I'd use json_encode($data) to keep the structure intact.

file_put_contents ( $filename , json_encode($data))

Exemple of what I get in logfile :

```
{"[Date]":"Thu, 15 Jun 2017 13:06:37 GMT","[Server]":"Apache\/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL\/1.0.2f PHP\/5.6.18","[X-Powered-By]":"PHP\/5.6.18","[Content-Length]":"7790","[Content-Type]":"application\/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

Advantages of this method is you can easily retransform it into an array from the logfile, if you want to.

Well, found another even easier method :

```
file_put_contents ( $filename ,  print_r($data, true));
```

Which keep the formatting even after putting them into the file.

Exemple :

```
Array
(
    [Date] => Thu, 15 Jun 2017 13:06:37 GMT
    [Server] => Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2f PHP/5.6.18
    [X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.6.18
    [Content-Length] => 7790
    [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
)
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php